# Can't run .jar classes from .sh on Linux that work on Windows via .bat

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, batch-file, jar

I'm having a strange issue trying to run classes from an executable .jar file on Linux that none of the existing question threads I've sorted through seem to be able to resolve.  I'll preface this in that I've never had to use Linux before and am only using it in this situation out of necessity, so it's possible I have overlooked something simple that I just didn't know could be causing the problem.

I can launch the classes from my .jar file without any issues on Windows via a .bat file with the following settings:

```
    start "MyServer1" java -classpath ./*;Server.jar infoServer/StartInfoServer
    start "MyServer2" java -classpath ./*;Server.jar loginServer/StartLoginServer
    start "MyServer3" java -classpath ./*;Server.jar chatServer/start
    start "MyServer4" java -classpath ./*;Server.jar gameServer/start
```

However, when I move to trying to launch these classes from the .jar on Linux, I get a "**could not find or load main class**" error.  My .sh file is set up like this, and is placed in the same directory as my .jar file:

```
    echo Starting Servers
    java -cp Server.jar infoServer.StartInfoServer
    java -cp Server.jar loginServer.StartLoginServer
    java -cp Server.jar chatServer.start
    java -cp Server.jar gameServer.start
    echo All Done Starting Server
```

I've used ls from the Terminal to verify the .jar and .sh were being recognized as existing where they should be.  (For future note, I'm using the Terminal from inside the directory containing my files.)  I've made sure to make use of chmod to be sure both the .jar and the .sh have read/write/execute permissions and used ls -l to verify those permissions were indeed present.  I've tried various forms of explicitly defining the classpath, such as using "/home/machine/Desktop/Folder/MyJar.jar", using pwd from the Terminal to ensure I'm getting the filepath correct.  I've checked over my Java compatibility. (1.7.0_65 on Linux, 1.8.0_45 on Windows, with the .jar being created in Eclipse using 1.7 Compliance settings.) I can use unzip MyJar.jar from the Terminal and it will properly extract all my class files, allowing me to verify that my .jar isn't corrupted on my Linux machine and that the paths to the classes I'm trying to run are still the same on Linux as they are on Windows.

I do apologize if this is just a problem of inexperience overlooking something, but I can't think of or find any indication of what the problem could possibly be.

EDIT:

I've updated the question with some screenshots related to the problem:

https://gyazo.com/0ae2a2701aae734db21ef7c29200283b - General File Setup.

https://gyazo.com/d735d9cee57b4a92078c4b624d012b8c - Running the Shell via Terminal.

Other notes:  jar -tf Server.jar works from the Terminal but not from inside the Shell script, which leads me to believe this may be some kind of visibility or pathing error, but I can't find any reason why that would be the case.

Comment: So, what is happening exactly? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96083/discussion-on-question-by-j-s-cant-run-jar-classes-from-sh-on-linux-that-wor).

Comment: Screen shots do not constitute an MCVE.  Follow the link I gave you if you are uncertain what does.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [appassembler-maven-plugin[(http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to automatically generate proper shell wrappers for both unix-like and Windows systems